# How do I pass the value selected from DropDown menu to a stateful widget right below it in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I need the user to select a value from a DropDown menu. Based on the value selected, a second DropDown is populated with values from the DB. I tried the following approach and it works when the user selects a value for the first time.

First DropDown:

```
            DropdownButton<String>(
                hint: Text('Please select your State/UT'),
                style: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryGrey),
                focusColor: kPrimaryBlue,
                value: selectedState,
                items: states.map((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedState = val;
                  });
                }),
            SizedBox(
              height: 25.0,
            ),
            selectedState == null
                ? SizedBox(
                    height: 0.0,
                  )
                : CampusSelector(
                    inputState: selectedState,
                  ),
```

Second DropDown Using a FutureBuilder (SearchableDropdown):

```
class CampusSelector extends StatefulWidget {
  final String inputState;
  CampusSelector({this.inputState});
  @override
  _CampusSelectorState createState() => _CampusSelectorState();
}

class _CampusSelectorState extends State<CampusSelector> {
  var allInstitutions = {};
  QuerySnapshot stateData;
  List<DropdownMenuItem> listOfDistricts = [];
  List<DropdownMenuItem> listOfInstitutions = [];
  List<DropdownMenuItem> listOfInsAndDisTmp = [];
  List<DropdownMenuItem> listOfInsAndDis = [];
  Future<void> getStateData;
  List<String> institutions = [];

  Future<void> fetchInstitutions(inputState) async {
    List<String> institutionsTmp = [];
    listOfInstitutions = [];
    List<InstitutionAndDistrict> institutionsAndLocation = [];

    stateData = await _db
        .collection('institutions')
        .where('STATE', isEqualTo: inputState)
        .getDocuments();
    for (int i = 0; i < stateData.documents.length; i++) {
      String ins = stateData.documents[i].data['NAME_OF_INSTITUTION'];
      String dis = stateData.documents[i].data['DISTRICT'];
      institutionsTmp.add(stateData.documents[i].data['NAME_OF_INSTITUTION']);
      institutionsAndLocation
          .add(InstitutionAndDistrict(institution: ins, district: dis));
    }

    // Deduplication and Sorting

    institutions = institutionsTmp.toSet().toList();
    institutions.sort((a, b) => a.toString().compareTo(b.toString()));

    debugPrint(institutions.toString());

    for (int i = 0; i < institutions.length; i++) {
      listOfInstitutions.add(DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(institutions[i]),
        value: institutions[i],
      ));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < institutionsAndLocation.length; i++) {
      listOfInsAndDisTmp.add(DropdownMenuItem(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(institutionsAndLocation[i].institution),
          subtitle: Text(institutionsAndLocation[i].district),
        ),
        value: institutionsAndLocation[i].institution,
      ));
    }

    setState(() {
      listOfInsAndDis = listOfInsAndDisTmp;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getStateData = fetchInstitutions(selectedState);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getStateData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return SearchableDropdown.single(
              items: listOfInsAndDis,
              value: selectedInstitution,
              hint: "Please select your college/university",
              searchHint: "Select one",
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedInstitution = value;
                  for (int i = 0; i < stateData.documents.length; i++) {
                    if (stateData.documents[i].data['NAME_OF_INSTITUTION'] ==
                        value) {
                      selectedDistrict =
                          stateData.documents[i].data['DISTRICT'];
                    }
                  }
                  print(selectedInstitution);
                  print(selectedDistrict);
                });
              },
              isExpanded: true,
            );
          } else {
            return SizedBox(
              height: 0.0,
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

CampusSelector class is still a work-in-progress, hence the unruly bunch of lists to process the data.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. They are impossible to read for screenreaders and impossible to find through search engines. Please post code as text and format it properly. That said, please post a [mcve]. Your code looks okay, but with just that little snippet and no knowledge what a "CampusSelector" is or does, there is no way anybody here can help.

Comment: Thanks @nvoigt, I've replaced the screeshot with a code snippet. Please let me know if the context could be understood from the code provided

Comment: You talk about a second dropdown. There is no second dropdown in your code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @nvoigt : I've provided the entire CampusSelector class here. This is still being modified, hence the code isn't exactly elegant. Apologies for that! Also, the SearchableDropdown used in the CampusSelector is a package from pub.dev (searchable_dropdown 1.1.3).

Answer (score 0):

You populate your CampusBuilder class *once* in `initState`. If you want to populate it with different data on each `build`, you need to call the `fetchInstitutions` methods in the `build` method.

That will probably mean you have to use a `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: I tried implementing a FutureBuilder for the CampusSelector() widget but that too isn't working. I'm not able to paste the code here due to the length. 

Is there a way to simply retrigger the statement below when the data from another widget changes state? So that CampusSelector() would be called again whenever selectedState value changes...

selectedState == null
                ? SizedBox(
                    height: 0.0,
                  )
                : CampusSelector(
                    inputState: selectedState,
                  ),

Comment: You would still need a FutureBuilder. You could also move your business logic out of your display components, for example by using the Bloc pattern. If you have problems with the FutureBuilder and can post code, why not edit your question or even ask a new one.

Comment: Hi... I've edited the question to include the FutureBuilder code. Sorry about the noob questions, I am new to both Flutter ad stackoverflow.

Comment: You are still building your Future only *once*. You need to call it on every `build`. Once you get that done and it works, *then* you can think about whether you want to optimize it.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to call the future for every build? Remove it from initState and call it in the future parameter of the FutureBuilder?

Comment: Yes. Remove `getStateData = fetchInstitutions(selectedState);` from your initstate and add `final getStateData = fetchInstitutions(selectedState);` as the very first line of your build method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218281/discussion-between-yesharish-and-nvoigt).